# R avoid loop for count with conditions

Tags: r, performance, count, data.table

I am using R with the data.table package. 
I have a loop in which a count is calculated, but as it is a loop it is extremely slow. Now I want to somehow change it, so that it won't take days to be calculated.

I have a dataset and I want to count how often this person already appears in the dataset. When firstname, surname, and birthdate (birthday, birthmonth and birthyear) are the same, it is the same "person". However, the problem that I have is, that the date is also important. So, if this person that I am looking at, appears in the dataset I have to check if the date of the "same person" lies before the date of the person that I am looking at. Hence, the same person must be known before the person that I am looking at.

I also then want to calculate the average time between those entries.
Here is my current solution (which works but is super slow):

```
library(data.table)
data <- data[order(-persondatetime)]
vec_countperson <- numeric(nrow(data))
vec_time <- numeric(nrow(data))

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  vec_countperson[i] <- data[firstname == data[i, firstname] &
                                   surname == data[i, surname] &
                                   birthdate == data[i, birthdate] &
                                   persondatetime < data[i, persondatetime], .N]
       vec_time[i] <- data[firstname == data[i, firstname] &
                                   surname == data[i, surname] &
                                   birthdate == data[i, birthdate] &
                                   persondatetime < data[i, persondatetime], 
                                   mean(abs(diff(c(persondatetime, data[i, persondatetime]))))]
}


data[, countperson := vec_countperson]
data[, timebetweenentries := vec_time]
```

An example data.table would look like this:

```
data <- data.table(
  firstname = c("Paul", "Jens", "Jens", "Jens","Paul", "Dieter"), 
  surname = c("Mueller", "Mustermann", "Mustermann", "Mustermann", "Mueller", "Brian"), 
  birthdate = as.Date(c("1960-05-08", "1960-05-08", "1960-05-08",
                        "1960-05-08", "1960-05-08", "1960-05-08")), 
  persondatetime = as.POSIXct(c("2018-05-01 23:18:38 CET", "2018-03-01 23:18:38 CET",
                                "2018-06-01 23:18:38 CET", "2018-04-01 23:18:38 CET", 
                                "2018-04-06 23:18:38 CET", "2018-04-08 23:18:38 CET")))
```

The expected output is:

```
   firstname    surname  birthdate      persondatetime countperson timebetweenentries
1:      Jens Mustermann 1960-05-08 2018-03-01 23:18:38           0                NaN
2:      Jens Mustermann 1960-05-08 2018-04-01 23:18:38           1           30.95833
3:      Paul    Mueller 1960-05-08 2018-04-06 23:18:38           0                NaN
4:    Dieter      Brian 1960-05-08 2018-04-08 23:18:38           0                NaN
5:      Paul    Mueller 1960-05-08 2018-05-01 23:18:38           1           25.00000
6:      Jens Mustermann 1960-05-08 2018-06-01 23:18:38           2           45.97917
```

Do you have any ideas how I can avoid the loop? I have thought of other ideas but my problem is always the thing with the date!

Comment: u might want to use non-equi self join: `data[, countpax := data[data, on=.(firstname, surname, birthday, birthmonth, birthyear, persondatetime<persondatetime), .N, by=.EACHI]]`

Comment: Maybe you are looking number of value for each group. `setDT(df)[, countperson := .N, by = list(firstname, surname, birthday, birthmonth, birthyear, persondatetime)]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use code similar to what @chinsoon12 posted in his comment to recreate the countperson column.

```
data[data, 
     on=.(firstname, surname, birthdate=birthdate, persondatetime > persondatetime),
     countperson:=.N, 
     by=.EACHI]
data[, countperson := coalesce(countperson, 0L)]
```

The data.table syntax for this update join is `X[I, on=.(conditions), var:=.N, by=.EACHI]`. For each row in the data.table `I`, the rows in `X` matching `conditions` are found. Using the `by=.EACHI` argument groups the results from this join by the rows in `I`. In data.table, the `.N` symbol represents the number of rows per group. In this case, for each row in `I`,  `.N` is the number of rows in `X` that matched based on `conditions`. If a row in `I` has no matching rows in `X`, then `.N` is NA, which we set to 0 using coalesce in the next line.

One way to recreate your timebetweenentries variable is to group by the columns that indicate rows belong to the same person, calculate the mean difference in persondatetime per group, and assign that to a column in your data.table. If you want time between successive entries then you should sort persondatetime before you get the differences.

The code below does all of the sorting at once using data.table's setkey function. This should speed up the grouping and avoiding the call to sort(persondatetime) for each group.

```
setkey(data, firstname, surname, birthdate, persondatetime)
data[, timebetweenentries := mean(abs(diff(persondatetime)), na.rm=T)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code, and it worked for the counperson variable, but for the timebetweenentries  it does not work. I tried it like this:
`setkey(data, firstname, surname, birthdate, persondatetime)
data[data, 
     on=.(firstname, surname, birthdate=birthdate, persondatetime > persondatetime),
     timebetweenentries:= mean(abs(diff(persondatetime))), 
     by=.EACHI]`

But it gives me only "NA secs". Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, adding the na.rm=TRUE argument to mean should fix that.  diff returns an NA for the first value since there is no previous value to take the difference of.  mean returns an NA if any of the elements are NA, but that can be changed by using the remove na argument, 'na.rm' and setting it to TRUE.